# Index-wise Replacement of String Data in Python

Tags: python, indexing, binaryfiles, str-replace

I newbie just Started to learning Python from YouTube, I am trying to make a program to replace
old binary Numbers to new binary Numbers, and facing problem while replacing numbers. want to replace index-wise
My file (1x.txt) data is like this...

`(01010110110111011110111101111011110101101101101011011011010101010101010101011101110101110111101)`

It's a Random data but it is in form of 01, 011, 0111 and 01111.
I want to replace "010" to "0", "0110" to "00", "01110" to "000" and "011110" into "0000" So with above given numbers my results should be
(0101 011011 011101111 0111101111 0111101 011011 01101 011011 01101 0101 0101 0101 0101 01110111 010111 0111101)
(01    0011   0001111   00001111  00001    0011   001   0011   001   01   01   01   01   000111   0111   00001)
so Far I tried to make a program that can do the task but its taking toooooooo much time, for just 8MB file it's taken more then 2 hours
so Anyone can suggest me a better way to do the same,
My is mentioned below

```
def bytes_from_file(filename):
    newstring = ''

    old_list = ['010', '0110', '01110', '011110']
    new_list = ['0', '00', '000', '0000']

    with open(filename, "rb", buffering=200000) as f:
        while True:
            try:
                chunk = f.read()

            except:
                print('Error while file opening')
            if chunk:

                chunk2 = chunk.decode('utf-8')
                n = len(chunk2)

                i = 0
                while i < n:
                    flag = False
                    for j in range(6, 2, -1):

                        if chunk2[i:i + j] in old_list:
                            flag = True
                            index = old_list.index(chunk2[i:i + j])
                            newstring = newstring + new_list[index]

                            i = i + j

                            break
                    if flag == False:
                        newstring = newstring + chunk2[i]
                        i = i + 1
                        newstring=''.join((newstring))

            else:
                try:
                    f = open('2x.txt', "a")
                    f.write(newstring)
                    f.close()

                except:
                    print('Error While writing into file')

                break


bytes_from_file('1x.txt')
```

Comment: Does your solution give you a *correct* result? Your file is a text file?

Comment: What is the rule for splitting the string of ones and zeros into varying length strings?

Comment: Why do you open the text file in binary mode then decode it to a string? why don't you just open it as a string?

Comment: I notice you have tagged this question as `binaryfiles`, but the file you are working with is **not** what that means.

Comment: Thanks wwii, and Karl Knechtel. want to clear your doubts, Now I am using Txt file for experiment, but later I want to perfume this task on deferent file format such as jpg, mp4, xls...., it's is a Data compress system that can reduce file size as many time as you want.. I am still experimenting .... Once it will finalize, I will Back to you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are greatly overcomplicating this in general, but the most important problem is here:

```
newstring = newstring + chunk2[i]
i = i + 1
newstring=''.join((newstring))
```

`newstring` is already a string, which you build by repeatedly concatenating substrings (like `newstring + chunk2[i]`). This means that `''.join((newstring))` treats *the string* as an iterable, and joins it up by taking it apart into *each letter* and doing the join operation. And it does this *every time that `old_list` doesn't match*, getting slower and slower as the string gets longer. The `newstring=''.join((newstring))` step *actually has no effect*, but Python can't optimize it out. On the flip side, using technique like `newstring + chunk2[i]` to build the string, defeats any purpose that `''.join` could have.

If your plan is to build a single string, you do still want to use `''.join`. But you want to use it *once*, and you want to use it on a *list* of the substrings:

```
# initially, set
newstring = []
# any time you find something else to append to the output:
newstring.append(whatever)
# one time, right before opening the output file:
newstring = ''.join(newstring)
```

That said, there are other approaches. Rather than building up a list, one useful technique is to use a *generator* to `yield` each piece that needs to be written. Then you can either iterate to write those, or build the joined-up string before writing (like `''.join(my_generator_function())`). Or you can have both files open, and just `.write` each output chunk as you determine it from the input.

Comment: Hi Karl Knechtel, As I mentioned in my Question. I am newbie, It is Kind request to you, Please could you Apply You Aspects/Logics/method in My code. and modify my code.